# Is it possible to change the inputs of a tkinter pop up box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a popup box that appears when the use presses a button. The box contains a dropdown menu where you can choose some input. If the color option is chosen, I want another dropdown menu to appear. If coord is chosen, I want a Entry to appear. Is this possible? My code is currently the following, but it doesn't work as expected:

Edit: Below is runnable code. I am currently trying to have the box change in the constructor, but I don't think that's the way to do it. What I want is that when the top dropdown is changed from color to x or y, the second dropdown becomes a Entry box so user can type into it.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class NewInputPopup:
    def __init__(self, parent, types, valueExpected=False):
        self.valueExpected = valueExpected
        self.parent = parent
        top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.typeVar = tk.StringVar(top)
        self.typeVar.set(types[0])
        option = tk.OptionMenu(top, self.typeVar, *types)
        option.pack()

        tk.Label(top, text="Value").pack()
        self.e = tk.Entry(top)
        self.choice = tk.OptionMenu(top, self.typeVar, *['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green'])
        # Part that needs to change
        if valueExpected:
            if self.typeVar.get() == 'color':
                self.e.pack_forget()
                self.choice.pack()
            else:
                self.choice.pack_forget()
                self.e.pack(padx=5)

        top.bind("<Return>", self.ok)
        b = tk.Button(top, text="OK", command=self.ok)

        b.pack(pady=5)

    def ok(self, event=None):
        if self.valueExpected:
            self.parent.createNewParameter(self.typeVar.get(), self.e.get())
        else:
            self.parent.createNewParameter(self.typeVar.get())
        self.top.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
c.pack()

PARAM_TYPES = ['color', 'x', 'y']

NewInputPopup(root, PARAM_TYPES, True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can dynamically change almost every aspect of a tkinter widget.

Comment: So how should I go about doing this? Is there a way to give a option menu an "onClick" function?

Comment: create simple, working example so everybody could run it and show solution.

Comment: I added the working code. Thank you!